# Gnucash migration

Tags: windows, gnucash

I am switching from Windows to Ubuntu 22.04 and want to use Gnucash.  How do I migrate the information from my Windows-based Gnucash to the Ubuntu one?  I've tried to go through the manual and searched YouTube videos to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does "to no avail" mean you can't find instructions, or that the instructions you found failed somehow?

Comment: https://cvs.gnucash.org/docs/C/gnucash-guide/basics-migrate-settings.html

Comment: Both, Steeldriver.  I clicked on the link from ckhan (thank you) and am such a newbie I need to have someone interpret for me.  Plus, I cannot find where the files are stored...I'll give it another go, but I really need a very VERY simple explanation, step by step, or a video.